# Dictionary with tuple keys and two lists as values, where a value is added to just one of the lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a set of integers in the form of a tuple forming my keys `(a,b)`.
I need to construct a dictionary where, for each key, a value (float) is put in one of the two lists that acts as pair-value:

```
(a,b) : [x_list,y_list]
```

I am constructing the dictionary from a txt file where each line has the tuple `(a,b)` and ONE of either `x` or `y`-type value that should be added to the list. However, I fail to understand how this can be done.

To be more precise:

if the txt file contains:

```
15,17,x_type,-1.1
15,17,y_type,44
1,2,y_type,-0.38
15,17,y_type,5
```

the dictionary should produce

```
d: {(1,2): [[], [-0.38]] , (15,17): [[-1.1], [5,44]]
```

What I am trying:

```
example = ['15,17,x_type,-1.1','15,17,y_type,44','1,2,y_type,-0.38','15,17,y_type,5']

for _ in example:
    [a,b,val_type,val] = _.split(',')
    if val_type == 'x_type':
       d[(a,b)] = [val,]
    if val_type == 'y_type':
       d[(a,b)] = [,val]
```

The syntax allows for `[x,]`, but does not for `[,y]`. Why?

Comment: please show a [mcve] instead of snippets

Comment: I did just now. Indeed can help running it quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lists can contain trailing commas. `[x,]` is the same as `[x]`. To append to a specific nested list, select the one you want by index:

```
if type == 'x_type':
   d[(a,b)][0].append(x)
elif type == 'y_type':
   d[(a,b)][1].append(y)
```

This assumes that you make a new nested list as soon as you encounter a key:

```
if (a, b) not in d:
    d[a, b] = [[], []]
```

Another nice syntactic trick is that anything with commas in an indexing expression is interpreted as a tuple. That means that you can write `d[(a, b)]` as `d[a, b]`.

Comment: I have tried previously something similar. 
Running this, I get: `KeyError: ('a', 'b')`
The trick you showed however is making the code more elegant! Thanks :)

Comment: @nyw. Just to make sure I understood your comment, does the code you ended up writing work or not? The `if (a, b) not in d:` check should be done *before* the type check by the way, in case it wasn't clear from the answer.

Comment: Indeed the code was not working because I did not initialize the dictionary as you showed. Now I have understood the check and it works well! Thank you!!

Comment: @nyw. Glad it worked for you. I posted an answer with a bit more insight to one of your older questions too.